# Game App Crashes when Application.Quit()

Tags: android, crash, unity-game-engine, exit

Iam Using Adcolony and Vungle together in my game, everything is working fine but when Quit the game with Application.Quit() game close but a popup is thrown with text "Unfortunately app crashed".

Here i have attached the adb logcat output from 
"Quit" is the last debug / print from Unity after that Android does its thing and throws the popup.

I need to fix that please help.

```
 03-30 17:56:35.471 26670 26684 I Unity   : Quit

 03-30 17:56:35.471 26670 26684 I Unity   : Stacktrace is not supported on this platform. 

 03-30 17:56:35.471 26670 26684 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)

 03-30 17:56:35.471 26670 26684 I Unity   : 

 03-30 17:56:35.841  2253  2253 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

 03-30 17:56:35.841  2253  2253 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/on7xeltedd/on7xelte:6.0.1/MMB29K/G610FDDU1AQA2:user/release-keys'

 03-30 17:56:35.841  2253  2253 F DEBUG   : Revision: '3'

 03-30 17:56:35.841  2253  2253 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'

 03-30 17:56:35.841  2253  2253 F DEBUG   : pid: 26670, tid: 26688, name: Thread-5757  >>> com.AxisEntertainmentLTD.BabyHazelFoodTruck <<<

 03-30 17:56:35.841  2253  2253 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8

 03-30 17:56:35.891  2253  2253 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000008  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000000

 03-30 17:56:35.891  2253  2253 F DEBUG   :     r4 d2128e70  r5 d2128eac  r6 d2128e70  r7 00000001

 03-30 17:56:35.891  2253  2253 F DEBUG   :     r8 00000001  r9 ddbbf530  sl 00000000  fp ddbbf678

 03-30 17:56:35.891  2253  2253 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000063  sp ddbbf4e0  lr de99ddf0  pc de99de44  cpsr 600b0010

 03-30 17:56:35.891  2253  2253 F DEBUG   : 

 03-30 17:56:35.891  2253  2253 F DEBUG   : backtrace:

 03-30 17:56:35.891  2253  2253 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00105e44  /data/app/com.AxisEntertainmentLTD.BabyHazelFoodTruck-1/lib/arm/libunity.so

 03-30 17:56:35.891  2253  2253 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 001064f0  /data/app/com.AxisEntertainmentLTD.BabyHazelFoodTruck-1/lib/arm/libunity.so

 03-30 17:56:35.891  2253  2253 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00106e2c  /data/app/com.AxisEntertainmentLTD.BabyHazelFoodTruck-1/lib/arm/libunity.so

 03-30 17:56:35.891  2253  2253 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 002deed8  /data/app/com.AxisEntertainmentLTD.BabyHazelFoodTruck-1/lib/arm/libunity.so

 03-30 17:56:35.891  2253  2253 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 0044bc68  /data/app/com.AxisEntertainmentLTD.BabyHazelFoodTruck-1/lib/arm/libunity.so

 03-30 17:56:35.891  2253  2253 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 008f5c5c  /data/app/com.AxisEntertainmentLTD.BabyHazelFoodTruck-1/lib/arm/libunity.so

 03-30 17:56:35.891  2253  2253 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 0000fe94  <unknown>

 03-30 17:56:36.001  2612  2808 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b97e3fe u0 com.AxisEntertainmentLTD.BabyHazelFoodTruck/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t140 f}

 03-30 17:56:36.001  2612  2808 D ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.acquire()

 03-30 17:56:36.041  2612  2808 I ActivityManager: Config changes=480 {0 1.0 themeSeq = 0 showBtnBg = 0 ?mcc?mnc en_GB ldltr sw360dp w360dp h616dp 480dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.151}

 03-30 17:56:36.221  2612  3711 D ActivityManager: post active user change for 0 fullscreen true isFloatingActivity() false isHomeActivity() true

 03-30 17:56:36.251  2612  2844 D ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.release()

 03-30 17:56:36.661  2253  2253 F DEBUG   : 

 03-30 17:56:36.661  2253  2253 F DEBUG   : Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02

 03-30 17:56:36.661  2253  2253 E DEBUG   : AM write failed: Broken pipe

 03-30 17:56:36.801  2612  3470 I ActivityManager: Process com.AxisEntertainmentLTD.BabyHazelFoodTruck (pid 26670)(adj 9) has died(148,1363)

 03-30 17:56:36.801  2612  3470 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 26670

 03-30 17:56:36.831  2612  3470 D ActivityManager: removeProcessNameLocked mProcessNames.remove pid=26670 ,hash=64744237 ,name=com.AxisEntertainmentLTD.BabyHazelFoodTruck
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `if (!Application.isEditor) System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();`

Comment: This doesn't work on my S8.  Perhaps Android doesn't give apps permission to do this anymore?